# Query to store order as value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this simple table of players

```
id | name | score | place
```

I would like to know if there is a query that would let me sort the players by `score` and update the `place` according to the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `update`, assuming that `id` is unique on each row:

```
update players
    set place = p.new_place
    from (select p.*, row_number() over (order by score) as new_place
          from players p
         ) p
    where players.id = p.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE players
  SET place=ordered_place
 FROM (SELECT id, 'place' AS ordered_place
         FROM players
        ORDER BY score
      ) AS t1 
WHERE players.id=t1.id;
```